# Xamarin form: Unable to styling for custom view

Tags: forms, xamarin, styles, resourcedictionary

I having trouble of creating a style for Custom View.

```
 <Style x:Key="cardStyle" TargetType="local:ExtendedFrame"> 
            <Setter Property="ShadowColor" Value="#B7BDC9"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="ShadowRadius" Value="5"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="ShadowOpacity" Value="0.8"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"></Setter> 
            <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="true"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="12"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,20,20,20"></Setter>
        </Style>
```

The message say: Position 12:25. Can't resolve ShadowColorProperty on ExtendedFrame

I have placed a correct namespace : xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Provider"

Comment: Can we have a look at your ExtendedFrame code. Do you have a ShadowColor bindable property?

Comment: I just found out I need to set static and readonly